# The usage of 'a' in front of a comparative

Tags: grammaticality, comparatives

Is this sentence correct? I'm not sure if adding an 'a' in front of 'more' is OK.

> To enable **a** more accurate spatial normalization process, manual re-orientation and positioning of the PET image were performed.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. There is no way to answer your question without knowing what _A..._ represents. Is it a singular or plural noun? Is it a count or uncount noun? After editing your question to make this clear, you may find the question migrated to _English Language Learners_, which is a more suitable site than ELU. Without editing, your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: The whole sentence is "To enable a more accurate spatial normalization process, manual re-orientation and positioning of the PET image were performed."

Comment: Thanks. Since _process_ is a singular count noun, you need the indefinite article _a_ in front of the comparative adjective.

Comment: @Shoe That's not the reason for the article. While the article is of course needed, it is for a different reason.

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.